# Scope of methods with arrays

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I have these methods:

```
def num n
  n += 10
end

def arr a
  a << "TEST"
end
```

After calling the methods on a number and an array respectively, the array is changed:

```
x = 10
num(x)
x # => 10

z = [1, 'hi', "Byron"]
arr(z)
z # => [1, 'hi', "Byron", "TEST"]
```

Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: where is `number_adder` defined in your code?

Comment: Code in question has nothing to do with JavaScript. Please only use tags that are relevant to the specific problem

Comment: @charlietfl guess he said he tried same code with JS.

Comment: @SilvioCro The code shown wouldn't work in javascript so just mentioning the word doesn't make it a relevant tag

Comment: This is not a "scope" question at all, it is a value/reference type question. It has nothing to do with the scope of the argument, and everything to do with the type of the argument.

Comment: What direction do you want to be pointed to? It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `z = [...]` you are creating a new instance of Array in the memory and storing a reference to it in the local variable z.

```
 z = ['foo']
 b = z
 y = ['foo']
 z.object_id # => 70314403278880
 b.object_id # => 70314403278880 (same object)
 y.object_id # => 70314411394940 (a different object)
```

When calling `arr(z)`, what you are actually passing to the method is a reference to the array instance, not the array itself or a pointer to the local variable.

As the reference points to an array, you can do things to it, such as add elements. The same goes with strings and other "non-constant" objects. You can't modify a number.

When you call `x = 10` you are assigning the object id of `10` (usually `21`) to the local variable `x`.

```
x = 10
y = x
z = 10
x.object_id # => 21
y.object_id # => 21
z.object_id # => 21
```

When you call `num(x)`, you are actually calling `num(x.object_id)`. The method-local variable `n` is used to store the reference, but the method never receives a reference to the local variable `x` that you used, `x` would no longer be a local variable in that case.

When the method does `n += 10` it changes what `n` points to, not what `x` points to.

So, in a way, what your example is "trying" to do is `10 = 10 + 10`. After this, the value of `10` would be 20 from there on forwards and `10 + 1` would now return `21`.

Other objects that behave like this include for example `true`, `false`, `:symbols`.